# Sort option while browsing content from selection in admin interface ezpublish

Tags: ezpublish

I have added `object relations` attribute in my content class. When i want to add a related object from that content class object i see a browse window option. Here i can select the related object.

But problem is i cannot sort these objects. I am attaching an screenshot. I want to get a 'published date' sorting option. How to achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible.
Maybe you can use the search to find the correct object.